# How to compare strings in GML

Tags: game-maker, gml

After reading the documentation I have not found what is the correct way to compare two strings in GML. I've tried the comparator '==' and doesn't seem to work (probably compares that they are the same object, which they are not). Another thing I can think of is using string_pos function to get 0 if they are equal and -1 if not, but seems a little overkill. Is there a more efficient way of comparing two strings?

Comment: Yep, need use `==` for compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing anything in GML, you have to use a single '='. Other than in javascript or c#.

so it would be:

```
if "test" = "test"{
    return true
}else{
    return false
}
```

the code above will return true

But to test variables in other objects, you would use [objectName].[variable] .

Answer (score 0):

For Game Maker Studio EA 1.99+

The right way to compare strings is using ==

Also for Game Maker Studio 1.4+

But for Game Maker 8 or 8.1 i dont know.